# Can we use hair clippers?

Tags: halacha, shaving

According to [this article](http://www.zomet.org.il/Eng/?CategoryID=253&ArticleID=141&Page=1) by Tzomet, it is forbidden for Jewish males to shave their beards with a razor; however, most electric shavers (with the possible exception of "lift and cut" shavers) are allowed to be used.

What about a manual [hair clipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_clipper)?

This came up in an [answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/1829/59) over at Lifehacks, about alternative shavers for when an electric shaver breaks or otherwise ceases to function.

Comment: I re-read your question and realized i misread it before. I thought (i don't know why) that you were discussing using nail clippers when in fact you are not. That's why i deleted my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @msh210 ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @user6591 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50513/5323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same logic used with an electric shaver would apply here. If it's not "razor-sharp", it's fine.

There are a few different definitions; Rabbi Heinemann of the Star-K, shlit'a, in the name of R' Moshe Feinstein [suggests](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-shavers.htm) taking a whisker from someone's beard, and seeing whether the cutter can cut it the same way a razor would.

> Hagaon R' Moshe Feinstein זצ"ל , who permitted the use of electric
>   shavers used a criteria similar to the shochet who would demonstrate
>   how sharp his חלף (shechita knife) was.  To show the sharp edge of his
>   knife, a shochet would take a hair from his beard, and holding the
>   hair in one hand the shochet would see whether the חלף cut the
>   dangling hair.  If the hair was severed, the shochet's steel passed
>   the test.

My understanding is that a manual clipper works like a fancy set of scissors, is not "razor" sharp, and is therefore permissible.

Comment: I like the example taken from *shechita*; it's one of my favorite subjects :P